# Shapiro Wilk Test in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have an array A with 100 numerical values. 
I want to test whether data in A is normally distributed using the [Shapiro-Wilk test](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/stats-swgoft.html).

Si I write `B = stats::swGOFT(A);` on Matlab command line and I have the error:

```
??? B  = stats::swGOFT(A) Error: Unexpected MATLAB operator.
               |
```

Can someone please help me how can I use [`stats::swGOFT()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/stats-swgoft.html) correctly?

Comment: Do you have the [Statistics Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/statistics/) installed?

Comment: do you have [symbolic math toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/index.html) installed?

Comment: Yes, I have both Statistic and Symbolic math toolbox.

Comment: It would seem you need to assign `B := stats::swGOFT(A)`.

Comment: B := stats::swGOFT(A) gives me this error: ??? Undefined function or method 'B' for input arguments of type 'char'.

Comment: This question clearly not answered: the steps described below don't work.

Answer (score 1):

swGOFT is a MuPAD library, so you have to execute it from within MuPAD instead of from the MATLAB commandline itself. In the MATLAB commandline, type `mupad` and press enter. You'll get the so-called MuPAD notebook, where you can enter your command. And it should be `B := stats::swGOFT(A)` as Shai mentions in the comment.

Edit: To bring `A` from the Matlab workspace to the MuPAD workspace, you first have to change it into an object of type 'sym'. The steps would be:

1. Create a sym object from A with the command `S = sym(A)`
2. Create a named MuPAD notebook with `note = mupad`
3. Send the variable `S` to `note` with `setVar(note, S)`
4. Use `S` in the MuPAD commands instead of `A`, like: `B := stats::swGOFT(S)`

Comment: Yes! My array (double values) A  is saved in the matlab workspace.  Now that I put the command from MuPAF notebook, gives me this error now. B := stats::swGOFT(A) Error: invalid operand: integers, rationals or floats expected [stats::getdata.

Comment: I correctly sent S to note with setVar(note, S) and then I use S in MuPAD, but still I have the same error. The error message doesn't help so much to understand what is wrong.

Comment: I was sure I'd checked the steps yesterday, but perhaps I used a wrong variable. I don't get the same error though, I get "Error: Some data are of invalid type." 
This Matlab-Mupad interface is pretty murky area to me, so I'm not sure how to rectify this. It looked like the function feval might be the solution but it too produces the same "invalid type" error on the Matlab commandline. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It's been 6 years and Matlab says it will remove MuPAD, but still my answer might be useful to someone.

I used and modified sundar's answer. The steps are:

1. Make sure A is a row vector (i.e. `size(A,1)==1`)
2. Create a sym object from `A` with the command `S = sym(A)`
3. Create a named MuPAD notebook with `note = mupad`
4. Send the variable S to note with `setVar(note, 'S', S)`
5. In MuPAD notebook convert the variable `S` of type `Dom::Matrix()` to variable of type `DOM_LIST`: `S2:=coerce(S, DOM_LIST):`
6. Get the p-value: `B := stats::swGOFT(S2[1])`

The reason for steps 1 and 5 are the following. `coerce` function converts the `Dom::Matrix` to a list of lists, where each row of Matrix is a list. To have all elements in single list we need `S` to be a row vector.